# How to run a script on Login

Tags: login, scripts

I want to get a script started on each login from domain users... how to do it?
`/etc/init.d/` is on startup not on login afaik.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The startupfile for each user is in the file `.bashrc` in their home directory.

if you want it to be system wide (i.e. for all users) you can add your script to the end of `/etc/bash.bashrc`

Comment: how can i start the line ive added as root. i thoght the bash.bashrc would be started trhough root, but it is not allowed. how can i work this out?

Comment: Just log out and log in again, that should start your script. ( bashrc files are not executable but sourced.)

Comment: You could run the bashrc files by sourcing them...but that is not really the thing to do)